# Taylor expansion square

Tags: taylor-expansion

Consider the following expansion $$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{8}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{16}x^3 .. $$

> Show this equation holds by squaring both sides and comparing terms up to $x^3$.

I wonder, how can I square the right hand side?

Comment: would it be: $1+x=1+(ist-2nd+3rd...)(1st-2nd+3rd...)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$(a+b+c+d)^2=\underbrace{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}_{\text{the sum of square of all terms}}+\underbrace{2ab+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2cd}_{\text{the sum of the double products of the terms taken 2 by 2 }}$$
so we find

$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{8}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{16}x^3 ..\right)^2=\underbrace{ 1^2+(2\times 1\times\frac12 x)}_{=1+x}+\underbrace{(\frac12 x)^2-2\times \frac18x^2}_{=0}\\\underbrace{-2\times \frac12x\frac18x^2+2\times\frac1{16}x^3}_{=0}+\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

\begin{align}
(a + b + c + \ldots )^2  & =  (a+b+c+\ldots) \times (a+b+c+\ldots)   \\
& = a^2 + ba + ca + \ldots + a b + b^2 + cb + \ldots ac + bc +c ^2 + \ldots 
\end{align}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you identify $c=-x^2/8$, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{8}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{16}x^3 + \dots \right)^2 = \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{8}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{16}x^3 + O(x^4) \right)^2  =$$
$$= 1+ \dfrac{1}{4}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{64}x^4 + \dfrac{1}{256} x^6+1-\dfrac{1}{4}x^2 - \dfrac{1}{8}x^3 +  \dfrac{1}{8}x^3 +\dfrac{1}{16}x^4 - \dfrac{1}{64}x^5 + O(x^4) =$$
$$=1+x  + O(x^4)$$

Comment: Where does the $x$ come from?

Comment: $x$ has to be considered as a real number in a (narrow) neighbourhood of $0$. It's the same $x$ in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put $t=\frac 12 x-\frac 18 x^2 + \frac 1{16}x^3$ then, you get:
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{1+x}}=\sqrt{1+t}=1+ \frac 12 t--\frac 18 [t^2]_3 + \frac 1{16}[t^3]_3 ... $$
where $[P(x)]_3$ for a polynom $$P(x)=a_0+a_1 x +a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4 ... +a_n x^n $$ is:
$$[P(x)]_3=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3.$$

For example , since: $t=x(\frac 12 -\frac 18 x + \frac 1{16}x^2)$  we have :
$$t^2=x^2(\frac 12 -\frac 18 x + \frac 1{16}x^2)^2$$ then : $$[t^2]_3=x^2(\frac 14 -\frac 18 x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\root{1 + x}\equiv \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}x^{k}}$.

> \begin{align}
> 1 + x&=\pars{\root{1 + x}}^{2}
> =\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}x^{k}
> \sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose j}x^{j}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}x^{k}
> \sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose j}x^{j}
> \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\delta_{n,k\ +\ j}
> =\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}x^{n}\bracks{%
> \sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}
> {1/2 \choose j}\delta_{j,n\ -\ k}}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}x^{n}\bracks{%
> \color{#00f}{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}{1/2 \choose n - k}}}
> \end{align}
>   We have to prove the coefficient of $\ds{x^{n}}$
>   $\ds{\pars{~\color{#00f}{\mbox{the blue expression}}~}}$ is equal to $\ds{1}$ when
>   $\ds{n = 0,1}$ and, otherwise, it vanishes out.

However,
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}{1/2 \choose n - k}}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{1/2}
\over z^{n - k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{1/2}
\over z^{n + 1}}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}z^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{1/2}
\over z^{n + 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{1/2}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 + z \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
={1 \choose n}=
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcrcl}
1 & \mbox{if} & n & = & 0
\\
1 & \mbox{if} & n & = & 1
\\
0&&&& \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> Then,
>   $$
> 1 + x = \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}x^{n}{1 \choose n}= 1 + x
> $$