# Any translate $\rho (x-a)$ of the ReLu function has a polynomial approximation.

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

I'm struggling and would like some help understanding and beginning to prove the statement below. This is much different than anything we've done so far in class so any assistance is appreciated.

Prove any translation of the ReLu function $\rho (x-a)$ has a polynomial approximation, for $0\leq a \leq 1$.  (A direct proof of this, via Taylor series, is outlined in the text.)

i.e. We want to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\displaystyle\sup_{∈[0,1]}|(−)−()|<$.

Some definitions

A function $\phi  \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be polygonal if
it is continuous, and there is a partition of $[0,1]$
\begin{equation}
0= x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n=1
\end{equation}
so that $ \phi  $ is linear on each interval $x _{k-1} < x < x _{k}$, for $k=1 ,2 , \ldots, n $.

and

The RELU  function is $ \rho (x) = \max (0,x) $.  It was used by Henri Lebesgue in 1898 to give a proof of the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.  The argument has three steps. Use/prove them to prove the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

The proof mentioned in the question showed that:

$\sqrt{1-x}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^ \infty a_n x^n$

for $a_0=1$, and $a_n=\frac{-1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-3)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}$ for $n\geq1$

I believe the connection here is that $\frac{\sqrt{1+x}^2 -1+\sqrt{x^2}}{2}=\frac{x+\vert x\vert}{2}$.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What is meant by a "polynomial approximation"? Since $phi$ is continuous, by the Weierstrass approximation theorem, there exists a sequence of polynomials converging to $\phi$ uniformly. It sounds like you want to prove the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem specifically for translates of the $\rho$, but it's not clear if this is actually what you want. I am just guessing.

Comment: @DionelJaime yes, sorry it was not super clear. The original wording of the question was not the best so I edited it and added the proof that it referenced at the bottom as well as my best guess to what it's eluding to, though that would mean squaring the whole tailor series (possibly useful post regarding that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/940758/1130235) then applying the rest of the translations etc. though I'm concerned about adding the \sqrt(x^2).

Comment: You still did not answer what a "polynomial approximation" is. I could probably guess correctly what you mean by this, but I would not be sure since you did not say what it was.

Comment: Forgot to mention that you are correct in that it is Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, my bad.

Comment: You should edit your question. You are looking to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\text{sup}_{x \in [0,1]}||\rho(x-a) - p(x)|| < \epsilon$. The stuff about Weierstrass and $\sqrt{1-x}$ provides some context, but it's not relevant.